# Convert a Iterable into a list in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, list, reactjs

I have a map (string -> string) which I want to convert to a list to be able to call "map" on it to convert it to a list of other values. The background is, that I want to use it in a reactjs component like this:

```
<input type="select">
{props.options.entries().toList().map((type,i) => {
                return <option value={type[0]} key={i}>{type[1]}</option>
})
}
</input>
```

Now, entries() gives me an iteratable. But it it has no "toList". How can I do this conversion?

Comment: Have you tried just doing `entries().map(...)`? You are also missing an ending curly brace just FYI

Comment: I don't understand this code. Mismatched curly brackets and parenthesis.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it

Comment: @mhodges `entries().map(...)` gives me Property 'map' does not exist on type 'IterableIterator<[string, string]>'

Comment: @Nathan Where is that iterable coming from? Typescript?

Comment: The point goes how can you iterate through this iterable, can you do this with a simple for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react components' `render` function,

```
render: function() {
  return (
  <Root>
  ...
  {props.options.entries().toList().map((type,i) => {
    return <option value={type[0]} key={i}>{type[1]}</option>
  })
  ...
  </Root> )
}
```

is nothing different from:

```
render: function() {
  let optionList = props.options.entries().toList().map((type,i) => {
    return <option value={type[0]} key={i}>{type[1]}</option>
  }

  return (
  <Root>
  ...
  {optionList}
  ...
  </Root> )
}
```

and nothing different from:

```
render: function() {
  let optionList = []
  // iterate through this iterable(pseudo, as the iterable interface is needed)
  let entries = props.options.entries()
  while (entries.hasNext()) {
    optionList.push(entries.next())
  }
  optionList.map((type,i) => {
    return <option value={type[0]} key={i}>{type[1]}</option>
  }

  return (
  <Root>
  ...
  {optionList}
  ...
  </Root> )
}
```